# Question related uploading file using multipart/form-data via postman

Tags: contentversion, postman

I have done the following setup in Postman, but I keep getting following error -
[
{
"message": "Multipart message must include a non-binary part",
"errorCode": "INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST"
}
]

I am not very familiar with boundary search and how that should get translated into Postman when making a callout- My entity-content is
{"ContentLocation":"S","Title":"test","PathOnClient":"test.sh"}

I tried with ContentDocumentId as well in entity content, but looks like I am missing some settings. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have also read through Salesforce, but not able to translate that to Postman

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compatible_editions.htm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [Insert or Update Blob Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) if you haven't yet. First, the file must be selected as a file. In the VersionData key field, there's a dropdown that appears on hover.

[image: Text/File selection on hover]

Change it from Text to File, then select the file. Here's a screenshot of what that looks like:

[image: VersionData as File]

Second, `entity-content` should be `entity_content`, and its content type should be `application/json`.

Third, `filename` should not be there. Everything that describes the content version should be in `entity_content`.